# Нужны ли указанные запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Эта статья, как попытка осмысления происходящего, должна была появиться значительно раньше...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если приложение с союзом "КАК" имеет значение причинности, оно выделяется запятыми. В вашем предложении именно этот оттенок.

Comment: Спасибо большое.